# TFS Build vNext Custom Task to check code coverage

Tags: powershell, tfs, task

I've created a custom task to check the percentage of code coverage on our builds but I'm getting errors at runtime when run via vNext (on premise, not VSO). Running the same PowerShell script directly on the build server works.

The errors are due to a couple of variables not having a value. However, when run directly on the server those same variable have correct values.

From the output below, "1." returns differently and that may well be the source of the problem.

Has anyone else found issues when trying to interrogate TFS via the API in PowerShell when run in a custom task?

Here's the PowerShell responsible for the "1. 2. 3. 4." bits in the output below...

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a") | Out-Null
[Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a") | Out-Null
[Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a") | Out-Null
[Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client,Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a") | Out-Null

[String] $CollectionUrl = "$env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI"
[String] $BuildUrl = "$env:BUILD_BUILDURI"
[String] $project = "$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT"

$tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($CollectionUrl)
Write-Host "1. $tfs"
$service = $tfs.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestManagementService])
Write-Host "2. $service"
$teamproject = $service.GetTeamProject($project)
Write-Host "3. $teamproject"
$totalRuns = $teamproject.TestRuns.ByBuild($BuildUrl)
Write-Host "4. $totalRuns"
```

Here's the output from my build task...

```
2016-05-10T10:52:16.5856277Z Executing the powershell script: F:\BuildAgents\3\tasks\CheckCodeCoverage\0.1.0\CheckCodeCoverage.ps1
2016-05-10T10:52:16.7666452Z Desired Code Coverage Percent is 80
2016-05-10T10:52:17.4527107Z CollectionUrl = http://hvn******02:8080/tfs/**********/
2016-05-10T10:52:17.4537113Z BuildUrl = vstfs:///Build/Build/4708
2016-05-10T10:52:17.4547103Z project = HP
2016-05-10T10:52:17.4867134Z 1. http://hvn******02:8080/tfs/**********
2016-05-10T10:52:17.5017245Z 2. 
2016-05-10T10:52:17.5497201Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
2016-05-10T10:52:17.5507204Z ##[error]   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String )
2016-05-10T10:52:17.5517213Z ##[error]   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
2016-05-10T10:52:17.5527209Z ##[error]   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`3.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
2016-05-10T10:52:17.5527209Z ##[error]   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
2016-05-10T10:52:17.5537202Z 3. 
2016-05-10T10:52:17.5587208Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
2016-05-10T10:52:17.5597209Z ##[error]   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String )
2016-05-10T10:52:17.5607212Z ##[error]   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
2016-05-10T10:52:17.5617229Z ##[error]   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`3.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
2016-05-10T10:52:17.5617229Z ##[error]   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
2016-05-10T10:52:17.5627218Z 4. 
2016-05-10T10:52:17.5897235Z 0 is the Code Coverage. Failing the build
```

And here's the output when run directly on the same server...

```
PS F:\BuildAgents\3\tasks\CheckCodeCoverage\0.1.0> .\CheckCodeCoverage.ps1 -requiredpercent 80
Desired Code Coverage Percent is 80
CollectionUrl = http://hvn******02:8080/tfs/**********/
BuildUrl = vstfs:///Build/Build/4708
project = HP
1. hvn******02\**********
2. Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestManagementService
3. HP
4. TestRun instance 26465375
  BugsCount: 0
  BuildConfigurationId: 4047
  BuildFlavor: release
  BuildNumber: 0.0.0.21
  BuildPlatform: any cpu
  BuildUri: vstfs:///Build/Build/4708
  Comment:
  CompleteDate: 10/05/2016 11:52:15
  Controller:
  CreationDate: 10/05/2016 11:52:16
  DropLocation:
  DueDate: 01/01/0001 00:00:00
  ErrorMessage:
  Id: 3563
  IncompleteTests: 0
  IsAutomated: True
  IsBvt: False
  Iteration: HP
  LastUpdated: 10/05/2016 11:52:16
  LastUpdatedBy: 7261134a-7631-49fa-b554-9d1fa6684d73
  LastUpdatedByName:
  LegacySharePath:
  NotApplicableTests: 0
  Owner: 7261134a-7631-49fa-b554-9d1fa6684d73
  OwnerName:
  PassedTests: 2
  PostProcessState: 3
  PublicTestSettingsId: 0
  Revision: 5
  ServiceVersion: 11.42.0
  StartDate: 10/05/2016 11:52:15
  State: 3
  TeamProject: HP
  TestEnvironmentId: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
  TestMessageLogId: 0
  TestPlanId: 0
  TestRunStatistics: [0]
  TestSettingsId: 0
  Title: VSTest Test Run release any cpu
  TotalTests: 2
  Type: 4
  UnanalyzedTests: 0
  Version: 0
Code Coverage percentage is 100
CodeCoverage limit met
PS F:\BuildAgents\3\tasks\CheckCodeCoverage\0.1.0>
```

Comment: You should not use code coverage as a pass/fail condition for builds for a multitude of reasons.

Comment: You could use SonarQube to fail the build on complex conditions such as code coverage - setup a server, set a quality gate to fail if code coverage drops bellow x%, add SonarQube tasks to your build definitions check the option to "fail the build if the quality gate fails"

Comment: Otherwise, here's how we're collecting the code coverage information - maybe this helps: https://github.com/SonarSource-VisualStudio/sonar-msbuild-runner/tree/master/SonarQube.TeamBuild.Integration

Comment: @DanielMann - You are entitled to your opinion but that's all it is. Doesn't help solve the actual problem.

Comment: @BogdanGavril-MSFT - Thanks, I'll take a look at SonarQube